# Processing Linux SIGnals using Gambas

Tags: linux, signals, gambas

I would like to send a (as yet undetermined) SIGnal from a bash script to a Gambas program when a specific file has been changed.

How can I get my Gambas program to process this SIGnal?

Answer (score 1):

The `gb.signal` component allows you to manage signals. You can intercept them, ignore them, and so on. See http://gambaswiki.org/wiki/comp/gb.signal for the details.

Answer (score 0):

If the documentation is anything to go by, this doesn't seem possible. However, I would suggest asking the same question on the Gambas mailing list (and/or link to this question on Stack Overflow). Please report back if you get an answer via the mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.mail-archive.com/gambas-user@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01890.html and http://www.nabble.com/Question-about-signal-management-inside-gambas-console-program---td20626972.html, it is not yet possible.